# Scrape html table with rvest. Why it only extracts a limited number of rows?

Tags: r, rvest

everyone!

I could need a little help...

Need to extract **all** the rows from a table but it only extracts ten (10) results...why?

This is the code I used:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "https://cip.org.pt/associativismo/associados/"

CIP_html <- read_html(URL)
CIP_html

CIP_html %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table
```

Also tried the code on other webpages, and it worked fine... extracting all the rows.

I couldn't figure out what seems to be the problem with this one.

Can anyone help? How can I extract all the rows from the table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `RSelenium` solution

```
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)

remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath= '//*[@id="table_1"]') %>% 
  html_table()
# A tibble: 127 x 6
   Logo  Entidade                                                                                    Tipologia                   Setor Região  WEB              
   <lgl> <chr>                                                                                       <chr>                       <chr> <chr>   <chr>            
 1 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 2 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 3 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 4 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 5 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 6 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 7 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 8 NA    ""                                                                                          ""                          ""    ""      ""               
 9 NA    "ABIMOTA - Associação Nacional das Indústrias de Duas Rodas, Ferragens, Mobiliário e Afins" "Associação Multissetorial" ""    ""      "http://www.abim~
10 NA    "ACIB - Associação Comercial e Industrial de Barcelos"                                      "Associação Regional"       ""    "Norte" "http://www.acib~
```